# F12 (Go To Definition) opens ClassName[from metadata] instead of Source

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Today is Monday and I was working on a solution on Friday - today however my F12 (Go To Definition) isn't working?! I have a reference to a class with the namespace "Admin.DataHelpers".  From my ASPX code-behind, I call:

```
_dgPanes.DataSource = PaneHelper.GetPanesInWebpage(_id);
```

When I F12 on the "GetPanesInWebpage" I'm given a window titled: "PaneHelper [from metadata]" with a padlock on it and it's READ ONLY.  I cannot (being through the Visual Studio and Re-sharper menus) get it to take me to the class/method in the project.

It's a class INSIDE the main project, and NOT referenced.

Could one of the guys working on my machine of the weekend have changed some setting(s) I'm unaware of?

I've followed the other advice of deleting the .suo (and looked at the posts re the .ncb files), cleaned and re-built the project to no avail?!

Any ideas?  :\

Comment: FIXED IT:  Solution File was corrupt.  I cannot self-answer for 8 hours but see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561074/syntax-intellisense-broken for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

FIXED IT:

Solution File was corrupt. 
See this post: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8561074/syntax-intellisense-broken for a fix