# Syntax/Intellisense broken?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm working with Visual Studio 2010 which seems to have suddenly broken?!
I have a solution open, opened a class and added:

```
namespace Admin
{
    public static class SessionManager
    {
        public static IEnumerable<UserGroupAccess> this is is annoying and will actually     BUILD ?!?"!?!?!?!?!

... [rest of class code]
```

After a CLEAN SOLUTION > BUILD SOLUTION, I get a report of "Build Succeeded".  My Intellisense and syntax checking etc seems to have packed up!

Anybody had this problem before?

Comment: Have you tried closing and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes... and my PC.  I've got Resharper installed and I've tried disabling this also.  :\

Comment: STUPID stackOverflow SYSTEM :\  I cannot self-answer my question for 8 hours... so I have to post the resolution as a comment instead:

Fixed it!!
1. Closed Visual Studio.
2. Deleted the Solution (.sln) File from the solution folder.
3. Opened Visual Studio.
4. Opened the first/main project (from the broken solution).
5. Added the remainder of the projects that were in that solution.
6. Saved the new Solution File.
This appears to have worked!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it - Just for other FYI :

1. Closed Visual Studio.
2. Deleted the Solution (.sln) File from the solution folder.
3. Opened Visual Studio.
4. Opened the first/main project (from the broken solution).
5. Added the remainder of the projects that were in that solution.
6. Saved the new Solution File.

This appears to have worked!! :)

Comment: Believe it or not, 3.5 years on, this issue is still there.I simply closed Visual Studio, deleted the .suo file, and restarted, to get Intellisense back. (in Visual Studio 2013 Update 4), but thanks for the hint!